# Is it better to hg forget or ignore?

Tags: mercurial

I have some binary files that I don't need to commit. I need them for local. Should I do `hg forget binary-folder/` or add this line to `.hgignore`?

`glob:binary-folder/*`

Which one is better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following quote is from [this mailing list post](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2009-August/027072.html) by Martin Geisler.

> A file can be tracked or not, you use 'hg add' to track a file and 'hg
>   remove' or 'hg forget' to un-track it. Using 'hg remove' without flags
>   will both delete the file and un-track it, 'hg forget' will simply
>   un-track it without deleting it.
>
> Un-tracked files show up with a question mark in 'hg status', unless
>   they are matched by the .hgignore file. So when you 'hg forget' a file,
>   it will typically show up as un-tracked in 'hg status', unless you have
>   a line in your .hgignore that matches said file.
>
> Tracked files are never affected by the .hgignore file.

For your case, apparently ignore would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks! Now, what's bad about having an non-empty hg-status message? I know for some repos, I have that untracked problem. Thanks

Comment: @user423455 nothing bad about it that I can think of, but definitely it's extremely unpleasing to the eyes ---  a bunch of question marks hanging around all the time...

Comment: Having any files showing question marks just increases the chance of them getting added to Hg by mistake, or prevents the convenience of being able to just type 'hg add' with no arguments to add all new (wanted) files.

Comment: It also increases the chance of new files not being added because you didn't see them among the files that shouldn't be added. Ignoring unwanted files means that you can use `hg status` as an easy way to see if you have any outstanding source control talks to do.